# Numpy array with numpy arrays as objects

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I'd like to create a numpy ndarray with entries of type ndarray itself. I was able to wrap ndarrays into another type to get it work but I want to do this without wrapping. With wrapping a ndarray `x` into e.g. the dictionary `{1:x}` I can do

```
F = np.vectorize(lambda x: {1:np.repeat(x,3)})
F(np.arange(9).reshape(3,3))
```

and get (3,3) ndarray with entries `{1:[0,0,0]}` ... `{1:[8,8,8]}` (with ndarrays). When change `F` to `F = np.vectorize(lambda x: np.repeat(x,3))` numpy complains `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence`. I guess it detects that the entries as arrays themselves and doesn't threat them as objects anymore.

How can I avoid this and do the same thing without wrapping the entries from ndarray into something different?

Thanks a lot in advance for hints :)

Comment: Using `otypes=[object]` might get `vectorize` to work.  `vectorize` uses `frompyfunc`, but changes the returned dtype.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can (ab-)use `numpy.frompyfunc`:

```
>>> F = np.arange(9).reshape(3, 3)
>>> np.frompyfunc(F.__getitem__, 1, 1)(range(3))
array([array([0, 1, 2]), array([3, 4, 5]), array([6, 7, 8])], dtype=object)
```

Comment: Looks like we've found a new tool for creating object arrays of arbitrary shape and complexity. :)

Comment: @hpaulj ;-)   I'd still prefer the numpy chaps to add something like `ndmax` to the `array` factory. But for the time being this method may well be the least awkward.